# Is the AC compressor drawing a large load to the engine causing it to idle poorly?

Tags: honda, accord, rough-idle, rpm, compressor

This is for an 04 Honda Accord 2.4L that's been acting strange. When the car is running and AC is off, car runs fine while driving but when I come to a stop, the engine sort of shudders and RPMS increase from 750 - 1100 and come back down and this happens twice then goes back to normal. Also, when running the AC, same thing happens. Engine shudders and rpms fluctuate sporadically.

Any thoughts or recommendation on what to check would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A dirty throttle body can cause these symptoms. It is best to have it removed for cleaning. It is not possible to do a sufficient job without doing so. You can remove the throttle body and remove the sensors attached to it so they are not damaged by the cleaner. Then it can be cleaned with a can of throttle body cleaner and clean cloth. If it has electronic throttle special precautions should be taken to prevent damage to throttle. It's not expensive for a shop to do it, but they should do diagnostics first.